# How to share an associatedtype between two protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, associated-types

I need to declare two protocols, they both have associatedtypes:

```
protocol MyView {
  associatedtype DataType
  associatedtype LayoutType : MyLayout

  var data: DataType { get }
  var layout: LayoutType { get }

  func doLayout()
}

protocol MyLayout {
  associatedtype DataType

  func computeLayout(with data: DataType?)
}
```

With this current protocol definition, the `associatedtype DataType` of `MyView` is not really the same as the one in `MyLayout`:

```
extension MyView {
  func doLayout() {
    layout.computeLayout(with: self.data)
                               ^^^^^^^^^
    Cannot convert value of type 'Self.DataType' to expected argument type '_?'
  }
}
```

The compiler is telling us that the type is not the same.

Is there a way to share an associatedtype between two protocols to fix my issue? Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you mean to make a protocol that inherits from the other 2

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov - I already tried it (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58fb6e95549081ba8eff9c7fc81d6fc2) and it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it's possible for an implementation of `MyView` to have a `LayoutType` with a different `DataType` to its own `DataType`. Once [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) is implemented, you'll just be able to say:

```
associatedtype LayoutType : MyLayout where LayoutType.DataType == DataType
```

in order to enforce that conforming types must have a `LayoutType` with a matching `DataType`.

However, until this happens, the best you're probably going to be able to do is add the constraint to the extension – which will only make the default implementation of `doLayout()` available if the `DataType`s match.

```
extension MyView where LayoutType.DataType == DataType {
    func doLayout() {
        layout.computeLayout(with: data)
    }
}
```